# How return 0 instead of 0.0 with fillna()?

Tags: python, pandas

I replaced all the empty values in my DataFrame with .fillna(0, inplace=True) but it now displays 0.0 and I would rather have an integer (0) instead of a float (0.0).
Is there a way to do so?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Cheers

Comment: Is the rest of your DataFrame integers?

Comment: Yes, only integers

Comment: I does, indeed :) 
Thx a lot! 

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df = df.astype(int)